# EF + async = The context cannot be used while the model is being created?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

The setup is pretty standard. Created a view and also the repository with the SQL Server connection string. Passed the repository the view model and on the view model's constructor I call a collection from the repository. It was all working fine until I tried to do it asynchronously using the async/await combo but now I get the error "The context cannot be used while the model is being created" when calling the repository's collection.

Old working code:

```
void FillPeopleList()
{
  PeopleList = _repository.GetPeople();
}
```

New broken code:

```
async void FillPeopleList()
{
  await Task.Run(()=>
  {
    PeopleList = _repository.GetPeople(); // Error
  });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EF is not thread-safe.

You cannot use the same context on multiple threads.

Comment: @Manuel: Correct; it's `Task.Run` that runs on a different thread.  What did you think that does?

Comment: Wrap a method in a task. How can I run a void method with await then? (without spinning a new thread)

Comment: @Manuel: That doesn't make any sense.  The whole point of await is to wait for something to finish.  If it runs in the UI thread anyway, there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: You don't need separate threads to run stuff asynchronously. You use callbacks to make sure you don't block the thread. Await and async do the callback wrapping for you. In this case I'm saying continue doing stuff and when the repository responds continue with the block (there's nothing after but that's irrelevant).

Comment: @Manuel: But where / how do you expect `GetPeople()` to run?

Comment: I expect it to run on the same thread, just not blocking it. From the await/async documentation: Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context, using time on the thread only when it's active.

Comment: @Manuel: It's impossible to run code on a thread without blocking it.  Blocking a thread _means_ running code on it.

Comment: When the method is inactive, something else is happening, either code on a different thread (your case) or truly async network IO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10857/discussion-between-manuel-and-slaks)